# NSFileManager and NSDirectoryEnumerator Crash?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsfilemanager

The code below crashes at `walker = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:directory];`. The code executes OK on the first call to `refresh`, but crashes on the second (and subsequent) calls.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

```
- (void)refresh
{
    NSString* directory = nil;
    NSFileManager* fileManager = nil;
    NSDirectoryEnumerator* walker = nil;

    if(files == nil)
        files = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    else
        [files removeAllObjects];

    ASSERT(files != nil);
    if(files == nil) goto EARLY_EXIT;

    fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    ASSERT(fileManager != nil);
    if(fileManager == nil) goto EARLY_EXIT;

    directory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    ASSERT(directory != nil);
    if(directory == nil) goto EARLY_EXIT;

    ASSERT(directory != nil);
    walker = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:directory];
    ASSERT(walker != nil);
    if(walker == nil) goto EARLY_EXIT;

    NSString* file;
    while((file = [walker nextObject]) != nil)
    {       
        BOOL isDirectory = YES;
        if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:file isDirectory:&isDirectory] && !isDirectory)
            [files addObject:file];
    }

EARLY_EXIT:

    //if(walker != nil)
    //  [walker release];

    if(fileManager != nil)
        [fileManager release];

    //if(directory != nil)
    //  [directory release];
}
```

Comment: Please, please, PLEASE don't use gotos!!! (Seriously... read about this!)

Comment: I can't believe after 25 years I am again faced with the evil of goto! Hell, I didn't even know you could do that in Objective-C. Although, it does explain that one guy they burned at the stake back when I was with Apple.

Comment: > I can't believe after 25 years I am again faced with the evil of goto.
I learned it over 30 years ago - old habits die hard.

Comment: What kind of crash are you seeing? And have you verified that `NSHomeDirectory()` is returning what you expect, every time?

Answer (score 0):

*Turns out, that in iOS and 10.5 and later, you should not use `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` anymore. Having used Cocoa for nearly 15 years bit me on this one. I'll leave it as a warning to others* -- TechZen

<strike>Despite the many sins against good programming practice you've comitted in this code, your real problem is here:</strike>

```
fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
```

The NSFileManger is a singleton in every app. You don't initialize it yourself, ever. The proper way to obtain the singleton is:

```
fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
```

... which returns the singleton. You usually don't bother with an attribute or variable, however, and just use it thusly:

```
walker = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:directory];
```

You know your not supposed to use assertions in release code, right?

Comment: > Despite the many sins against good programming practice.
I'll take it that you don't care for goto's either. Personally, I really really don't care about the style as long as all return values are asserted and checked.

Comment: > The NSFileManger is a singleton in every app. You don't initialize
> it yourself, ever. The proper way to obtain the singleton is:
> fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
Hmmm... the Apple documentation I read stated `defaultManager` was not thread safe and `[[NSFileManager alloc] init]` should be used.

Comment: @noloader -- Hah! You're right that the docs now say not to use `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` in iOS and 10.5 and later. I got burned by old knowledge. Your not the only one with old habits it seems. Now, I have to go back and fix some code, a lot of code.

Comment: @noloader -- StackOverflow doesn't allow paragraph formatting in comments. Just bold, italic, code and links (all inline.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the same crash. Crashed in iOS 4.3 but worked fine in 5.0. Blrgh. I refactored by code to use the string enumerator instead of the url enumerator:

```
    NSFileManager* localFileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator* enumerator = [localFileManager enumeratorAtPath:path];
    for (NSString* file in enumerator) {
        // do stuff...
    }
```

Good luck. (and get rid of those gotos).